# Return UID attribute value using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, getattribute

I have a site that looks like this and I want to extract the contents of the uid field using firefox + selenium + python. There is only 1 UID per page.

```
<div class= "parent" >
   <div class="module profile" dcp="1" uid="90">
   ...
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

To make it concrete see the following:

```
<div class= "parent" >
   <div class="module profile" dcp="1" uid="[RETURN THIS]">
   ...
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried several techniques in selenium including using

```
browser.find_elements_by_name
browser.find_elements_by_xpath
browser.find_elements_by_class_name
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector
```

But none of them are able to return the UID. I either get an empty set or I only get the class (i.e. the entire module class rather than the attributes inside the DIV).

I saw some folks recommend the get_attribute selector but I was unsuccessful in applying it to this use case.

Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: please provide selenium script you tried..

Comment: The entire script don't have a lot of useful information. I believe I only need one line of selector code to get this. However I tried using things such as `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("module")[0]` but this returns the ENTIRE <div> to </div>. Also tried `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("module.profile")` but that again returns the children of the div instead of the attributes inside the initial div block. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the value of the attribute *uid* i.e. the text **90** you can use either of the [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  myText = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.parent>div.module.profile").get_attribute("uid")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  myText = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='module profile']").get_attribute("uid")
  ```

However it seems the attribute *uid* i.e. the text **90** is a dynamic element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.parent>div.module.profile"))).get_attribute("uid")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  myText = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='module profile']"))).get_attribute("uid")
  ```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```